# System time not same in two computers of same domain

Tags: windows-8.1

My computer and my colleague's computer (sitting next to each other) are connected to same domain running Windows 8.1 on identical hardware.

I am noticing a time difference of around 5 minutes between us. When verified with other near by colleagues my system's time seems to be in sync with others.

I am bit perplexed to see how two different computers can have different time which are in same domain. My understanding is that the time of the client systems will get sync with the time of the domain controller, even if the time is altered by the user.

We tried restarting the system, removed our computers from domain and attached them again - all but no result. Both systems gets powered down by end of the day and start every day.

The system administrator is also baffled and could not find any answers from Google search as well.

Any idea on how I could keep the system's time in sync?

Comment: time is synced with domain controller only if it is set to do so on the machine.

Comment: Please see [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/set-clock#1TC=windows-7) page. It says `If your computer is on a domain, you can't synchronize your clock with an Internet time server.` I agree that this statement and yours are different, but the corollary of this statement seems to contradicting with yours. Also, the "Time and language" page in PC Settings has the switch "Set time automatically" disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the time on the PCs using the "net time" command in a logon script if you want to be consistant.

like this: `net time \\<servername> /set /y`

Take a look at these links: [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/w32time/archive/2007/09/04/keeping-the-domain-on-time.aspx), [support.microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042)